# bidirectional communication using wcf for messaging

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0

I am creating a messaging module in our asp.net application by using WCF service. The functionality will be like a loggedin user can communicate with other logged in users. This type of functionality I have already done by using Web service, but now in this application I want to use WCF.

In my previous application we ware calling the web service method in fixed interval to get the message
but this approach unnecessary creating load on server which we want to avoid in this new application.

So I want to something like

When user sent message (Make a call to WCF service and store message) to other the notification should raise for that user then after that target user make call to WCF service for their message.

or

WCF service directly forward message to target user

Pleas suggest me is it possible by using wcf.? or what will be the best way to avoid unnecessary call to service. ?

Comment: Have you read about SignalR at all? I am sure you can do something like this in WCF, but signalR is more or less built for something like this, and the implementation is very simple

Comment: Can you please give me any link for signalR, I am not aware about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link to signalR:

http://signalr.net/

You can actually install it via nuget console. And here is a couple links to some walkthroughs and intros:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Damian-Edwards-and-David-Fowler-Demonstrate-SignalR

Good luck!